# Scroll in both directoins scroll in Jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to find a way to create a 2 direction scroll view in compose, but I cannto find anything valuable yet. Later I used https://github.com/jaredrummler/TwoDScrollView lib, but when I migrate to compose project I can't do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, because you try to combine 2 different frameworks.
You cannot use this lib in your compose project